# Can I use Hibernate Maven plugin to generate entity classes from SQL (DDL)?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, orm

I'm using hibernate3-maven-plugin to generate java entity classes.

Currently it is configured to use only an active database connection as input to do the task.
But I'm curious whether it's possible to generate the classes from SQL file (DDL) without the need to have an active database connection.